# Multiple brackets or parentheses with a text inside

Tags: brackets, text, parenthesis

[image]I need to write multiple brackets but not in mathematical mode; i need to write some texts inside, like the picture. I am trying everything but it seems impossible. I tried using package schemata, tkiz, showframe. I think i am probably not using in the right way.

Comment: how did you use it?

Comment: \newsavebox{\leftbox} \newsavebox{\rightbox}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\lrboxbrace}{s O{\{} O{\}} O{0.1\linewidth} m O{0.8\linewidth} m}{% %\lrboxbrace[<lbrace>][<rbrace>][<lwidth>]{<ltext>}[<rwidth>]{<rtext>}
\begin{lrbox}{\leftbox}% Left box
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}% starred/unstarred
  {\begin{varwidth}{#4}#5\end{varwidth}}
  {\begin{minipage}{#4}#5\end{minipage}}
 \end{lrbox}
 \begin{lrbox}{\rightbox}% Right box
\IfBooleanTF{#1}% starred/unstarred
{\begin{varwidth}{#6}#7\end{varwidth}}
{\begin{minipage}{#6}#7\end{minipage}}
\end{lrbox}
\ensuremath{\usebox\leftbox\left#2\,\usebox\rightbox\,\right#3}}

Comment: I insert this comand by using the \usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}

Comment: the problem with the package schemata is that when i try to insert an bracket inside another it becomes tiny and is impossible to write a text inside

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps this way might work, using a nesting of `\BL[<bullet>]{entry}` and , for bracing, `\level{<row 1> \cr <row 2> ...}`.  Column width is defined by `\levelwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\levelwidth{0.7in}
\newcommand\BL[2][$\bullet$]{#1\,\parbox[t]{\levelwidth}{\raggedright#2}}
\def\level#1{\unskip $\left\{\vcenter{\hbox{\shortstack{#1}}}\right.$\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\BL[]{Text here blah blah}
  \level{
    \BL{text text here here something} 
      \level{
        \BL{number}\cr
        \BL{other word}\cr
        \strut
      }
  \cr 
    \BL{another text here}
      \level{
        \BL{something}\cr
        \strut\cr
        \strut
      }
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**FOLLOW UP**

[NOTE: an even better version of this is presented at [Is there a better way of setting this tree?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313721/is-there-a-better-way-of-setting-this-tree/313740#313740])

Here, I address two extensions: 1) if some rows employ different numbers of columns, and 2) if columns need to be different widths (my latest EDIT).

If there are to be some entries with different numbers of columns, I introduce `\skipcol[<bullet>]{<column number>}`, which should be employed (perhaps successively) after a `\BL{}` of the last filled column.  The column number must be specified as an argument, since different columns can now have different widths.  The `[<bullet>]` optional argument may be needed, since different bullets have different widths, as well.

The column widths must be pre-specified in the definitions: `\levelwidth` (left most column width), `\levelwidthi` (width after left-most brace), `\levelwidthii` (width after 2nd brace), `\levelwidthiii`, etc. in the way of roman numerals.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{levelcount}
\def\levelwidth{0.7in}
\def\levelwidthi{1.7in}
\def\levelwidthii{.9in}
\def\levelwidthiii{.3in}
\newcommand\BL[2][$\bullet$]{#1\,\parbox[t]{%
  \csname levelwidth\romannumeral\thelevelcount\endcsname}{\raggedright#2}}
\def\level#1{\stepcounter{levelcount}%
  \unskip $\left\{\vcenter{\hbox{\shortstack{#1}}}\right.$%
  \addtocounter{levelcount}{-1}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\skipcol[2][$\bullet$]{\unskip\mbox{} %
  \hphantom{$\left\{\hbox{#1\,\parbox[t]{%
  \csname levelwidth\romannumeral#2\endcsname}{\mbox{}}}\right.$}%
  \ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\BL[]{Text here blah blah}
  \level{
    \BL{text text here here something} 
      \level{
        \BL[$\spadesuit$]{number} \skipcol{3}\cr
        \BL[$\spadesuit$]{other word}
          \level{
             \BL{A}\cr
             \BL{B}
          }
        \cr
        \strut
      }
  \cr 
    \BL{another text here}
      \level{
        \BL[$\spadesuit$]{something}\cr
        \strut\cr
        \strut
      }\skipcol{3}
  \cr
    \BL{here is a 1-column entry, must use \textbackslash skipcol}
      \skipcol[$\spadesuit$]{2}\skipcol{3}
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: even by using this i cant write a large text inside

Comment: @PoliTolstov by "large" do you mean big letters or long strings of text?

Comment: wait...i think got it by changing some variables in the command

Comment: long text, steven

Comment: @PoliTolstov Does increasing the value of `\def\levelwidth{0.7in}` help, which is the column width?

Comment: yes. it is helping. However i think it is increasing the width of all the three columns

Comment: i need to decrease the width of the first column and increase only the width of the third

Comment: @PoliTolstov Then set the value of `\levelwidth` to a value suitable for columns 2, 3, etc, and replace the opening line of the construct, `\BL[]{Text here blah blah}` with `\parbox[t]{.7in}{\raggedright Text here blah blah}`, where `[.7in]` is the desired width of column 1.

Comment: and if i wish to change the width of the second column too i have to proceed in the same way?

Comment: @PoliTolstov If you want to arbitrarily use different column widths, then I have to try to rework a solution allowing for that as a parameter.

Comment: ok. Could you explain to me what means "in" in [0.7in]? And raggedright, \BL, \shortstark and \cr? Because I am new in latex, and i think i could try making some changes here by understanding what means each thing. nevertheless i am already greatful.

Comment: @PoliTolstov "in" is inches (American length units), `\raggedright` prevents full justification of a paragraph, `\BL` is what I define in the preamble to  print a bullet and then a paragraph box, `\shortstack` is a intrinsic TeX macro for stacking things vertically, where `\cr` is the row delimiter of the stack (I think it stand for "carriage return").

Comment: @PoliTolstov See update for different column width entries.