# text nested curly brace

Tags: braces

So far I was able to write this but as you see is far from what I would like to achieve. I'm finding difficult to nest the braces. I would prefer to not use the math mode.

Can someone could please help me?

```
 $ 
\parbox{2cm}{atti tipici di iniziativa della p.g.}\left \{ 
\begin{array}{l } \parbox{3cm}{atti di coercizione personale}\\

\parbox{3cm}{atti di acquisizione probatoria} \left \{ \begin{array}{l } \parbox{3cm}{atti di acquisiszione probatoria soggettiva}\\
\parbox{3cm}{atti di acquisiszione probatoria soggettiva}\\
 \end{array} \right.
 \end{array}\right.
$
```

[image: this is what I would like to achieve]

Comment: I would probably do this in tikz instead, simply make nodes of specific widths, place them and use their coordinates to make brace decorations. The details on each piece can be found elsewhere on the site

Comment: `schemata` is made for this.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313792 for an example.

Comment: in my opinion is not a duplicate. Yesterday Thérèse suggested me to use schemata. Now I have some problems using the package and posted the second question.

Comment: @LucatryingtowriteinLaTex There is a `\schema` too many in your code: the one after `\schemabox{atti di acquisi-\\zione probatoria}` is unnecessary (and it has `\bigskip` as its second argument). I've removed it, see [here](https://pastebin.com/7nMtCQ79) for a fixed version.

Comment: Thank you very much Circumscribe, you solved my problem.. There is any way to add a caption and a label to the "graphic"

Comment: and it is possible to transform the "graphic" in a floating object? LaTex does strange things around it..

Comment: @LucatryingtowriteinLaTex: You could place it in a `figure` or `table` environment and give it a `\caption`. Or you can define your own floating environment using `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment` from the [`newfloat`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newfloat) package. If you want a caption without , there's `\captionof` from the [`caption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package.

Comment: @Circumscribe thank you again.. works perfectly. Last question how could I make a proper itemize inside schemata? if you see "accompagnamento coattivo per accertamenti sulla identità personale " is not properly aligned

Comment: Load [`enumitem`](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and use `\parbox{<width>}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=0pt]…\end{itemize}}`.

Comment: @Circumscribe thank you, you solved my issue and saved my holidays. Merry Christmas